# Concatenate pseudo selectors in css

Tags: html, css

I have a one question that i dont know resolve.

If I have, two different lists ul and ol and i want applicate style at the first element of the first list without use ol tag or js, only i want use css:

```
<div>
<h1>Title</h1><ul>
  <li>element_1</li>
  <li>element_2</li>
  <li>element_3</li>
  <li>element_4</li>
  <li>element_5</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>element_1</li>
  <li>element_2</li>
  <li>element_3</li>
  <li>element_4</li>
  <li>element_5</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

I test with:

```
div :has(li):nth-child(1) li {
  /* styles */
}
```

But i cant access to element of this way. Is possible resolve only with css?

Thanks, i cant find nothing to fix it

Comment: Style elements in only one of more lists isn't possible without specifying which one it should be. You can use `h1 + * li:first-child` (1st LI in first list next to h1) if your markup is always `h1 + list`. There is no general style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i write in my comment under question, you can use `h1 + * li:first-child`. It's very dependent on HTML markup.

Using `:has` selector you can use something like that...

```css
div :has(li) li:first-child {color: red;}
div :has(li) ~ :has(li) li:first-child {color: inherit;} /* return color from red for 2nd and next lists */
```

```html
<div>
<h1>Title</h1><ul>
  <li>element_1</li>
  <li>element_2</li>
  <li>element_3</li>
  <li>element_4</li>
  <li>element_5</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>element_1</li>
  <li>element_2</li>
  <li>element_3</li>
  <li>element_4</li>
  <li>element_5</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Or just `:has(li) li:first-child:not(:has(li) ~ :has(li) li)`

Answer (score 1):

The only possible way without using a strict `ol` or `ul` in the CSS is by using the element+element selector `+` and with `*` as a replacement.

```css
h1 + * > li:first-child {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title</h1>
  <ul>
    <li>element_1</li>
    <li>element_2</li>
    <li>element_3</li>
    <li>element_4</li>
    <li>element_5</li>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li>element_1</li>
    <li>element_2</li>
    <li>element_3</li>
    <li>element_4</li>
    <li>element_5</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree. I don't see a way to do this without either a global selector or including both list tags in the css rule.  +1